# VB6 - Passing an Array as the ParamArray argument of a function

Tags: sql, arrays, vb6, ado

We have this utility method in a VB6 COM library for executing parameterised SQL:

```
Public Sub ExecSQL(ByVal strSQL As String, ParamArray varParams() As Variant)
    'snip - ADODB data access
End Sub
```

Where varParams is a two dimensional array of SQL parameter information. Example usage would be:

```
ExecSQL("SELECT * FROM People WHERE Name = ?", Array("@p1", adVarChar, 10, "Smith"))
```

This is tried and tested code and works fine in normal usage. I am now in an unusual situation where the SQL string is a configurable value and could contain any number of parameters, so what I need to do is pass an unknown number of arguments in to the ParamArray. My attempt so far (simplified) is:

```
Function ExecConfigurableSql(sqlString As String, parameterValues() As String)

    Dim parameters() As Variant
    ReDim parameters(UBound(parameterValues)) As Variant

    For i = 0 To UBound(parameterValues)
        parameters(i) = Array("@p" + CStr(i), adVarChar, 1000, parameterValues(i))
    Next

    ExecSQL(sqlString, parameters) 'Type Mismatch
End Function
```

The attempt to execute the SQL throws a Type Mismatch error. Is there a way to pass an Array in to a function which expects a ParamArray? Or am I making an altogether separate mistake somewhere?

This is what the parameters look like with a dynamically built up array:

[image: Dynamic array]
And this is what they look like when passed with comma-separated ParamArray syntax (which works):

[image: ParamArray]

The structure looks the same to me.

Comment: Just a suggestion on the loop, I would use For i = LBound(parameterValues). For your error, can you break the program before you call the ExecSQL method and examine the paramters?

Comment: AFAICR the answer is no. You have to create a new array and copy the ParamArray entries into the new array, and then pass the new array instead.

Comment: In the first example you are passing an array of values. In the second you are passing an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

First, you never needed *ParamArray* in *ExecSQL()* in the first place as you're always passing **one** argument on the stack in addition to *strSQL*, i.e. an array of variants, which is

```
Array("@p1", adVarChar, 10, "Smith")
```

in the second listing. *ParamArray* is used to pass an undefined number or parameters **on the stack**, i.e. to be able to make calls like:

```
ExecSQL "SELECT * FROM People WHERE Name = ?", "@p1", adVarChar
ExecSQL "SELECT * FROM People WHERE Name = ?", "@p1", adVarChar, 10, "Smith"
ExecSQL "SELECT * FROM People WHERE Name = ?", "@p1"
```

*ParamArray* just take all the arguments passed on the stack and put them in an array for you.

So, you could have defined *ExecSQL()* as follow and it would have been the same thing **provided** your code get adapted to one-less Array() layer around *varParams*:

```
Public Sub ExecSQL(ByVal strSQL As String, varParams() As Variant)
    ' snip - ADODB data access '
End Sub
```

---

That being said:

Currently, the code in *ExecConfigurableSql()* transforms an array of strings (I presume field names), into the format expected by *ExecSQL()*, **except** that the (outer) array can (and will) contain **more than one element** of the sort Array("@p1", adVarChar, 10, "Smith").

Can *ExecSQL()* handle this? => **Problem #1**

[by the way, are all the fields 1000-char long??]

**Problem #2**: *parameters* is fine when you look at it from within *ExecConfigurableSql()*, but once you pass if to *ExecSQL()*, the *ParamArray* wraps it inside another array, so you really end up with (once in *ExecSQL()*) with something like this:

[image]

Now, you **have to** put the (unknown number of) parameters in an array, 'cause, well, you can't pass them on the stack to *ParamArray* since you don't know in advance the number of them. So you cannot remove the extra *Array()* wrapping from there.

You **could** get rid of the *ParamArray* in *ExecSQL()*, but **that would break** your existing *ExecSQL()* calls (for which *varParams* would only be wrapped once in an *Array()* instead of twice).

**Knowing all this, you have two choices:**

**(1)** Keep the declares as-is, and have *ExecConfigurableSql()* make multiple *ExecSQL()* calls within a *For* loop (btw, you declared it as a *Sub* so I presume it doesn't return any value); e.g.

```
Function ExecConfigurableSql(sqlString As String, parameterValues() As String)
    For i = 0 To UBound(parameterValues)
        Call ExecSQL(sqlString,  Array("@p" + CStr(i), adVarChar, 1000, parameterValues(i))
    Next
End Function
```

or

**(2)** Do the other way around, to improve the logic & consistency

- Since you can still play with the declaration & implementation of *ExecConfigurableSql()*, change the second parameter to expect an array of Array("@p1", adVarChar, 10, "Smith")-like members (and not just field names).

---

```
Function ExecConfigurableSql(sqlString As String, varParamsArray() As Variant)
Dim varParams() As Variant
    For i = 0 To UBound(varParamsArray)
        varParams = varParamsArray(i)
        ' snip - ADODB data access '
    Next i
End Function
```

- Take the code from within *ExecSQL()* and put it in *ExecConfigurableSql()* where indicated - **IMPORTANT:** You have to update your code to account for the fact that parameters have one less Array() wrapped around them.
- For *ExecSQL()*, remove the *ParamArray* keyword and treat the method as a special case of *ExecConfigurableSql()* where only one member is provided, i.e.:

---

```
Function ExecSQL(sqlString As String, varParams() As Variant)
    Call ExecConfigurableSql(sqlString, Array(varParams))
End Function
```